# How to add a second tag list using pelican-bootstrap3

Tags: jinja2, pelican

I would like to list the Lego sets I used to build my models just like tags but in a separate list. According to the pelican documentation this should be possible. But when I run `pelican content` I get

> `Tags` Animal / Duplo / MOC
>   `Sets` 1 / 0 / 5 / 7 / 1

instead of

> `Tags` Animal / Duplo / MOC
>   `Sets` 10571

I modified the [pelican-bootstrap theme](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-themes/tree/master/pelican-bootstrap3) from Daan Debie by adding `{% include 'includes/setlist.html' %}` to `article_info.html`.

This is what my `setlist.html` file looks like:

```
{% if article.sets %}
<span class="label label-default">Sets</span>
{% for set in article.sets %}
    <a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ set.url }}">{{ set }}</a>
    {% if not loop.last %}
        /
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

This is what my markdown file looks like:

> Title: Girafe
>   Date: 2015-11-29 14:22:20
>   Modified: 2015-11-29 14:22:27
>   Category:
>   Tags: Animal, Duplo, MOC
>   Sets: 10571
>   Slug: girafe
>   Authors: Yann Baumgartner
>
> ![Girafe][girafe]
>   [girafe]: {filename}/images/girafe.jpg  "Girafe"

I read through all the pelican questions on stackoverflow but couldn't find an answer. I tried the following:

- If I use the taglist code within setlist without changing any
  variables then the tags are displayed correctly
- Renaming the variable
  name to `set_numbers` didn't work.
- Removing `set.url` didn't work.

Am I missing something (a template file, a jinja2 filter)? Any hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pelican` doesn't process any non-standard metadata. It'll be left as a string. So, `article.sets` will be a single string containing `"10571"`. If you loop over that, you'll get individual characters. You need to process it yourself via a plugin or inside your template like:

```
{% if article.sets %}
<span class="label label-default">Sets</span>
{% for set in article.sets.split(',') %}
    {{ set|trim }}
    {% if not loop.last %}
        /
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

**PS**: Also, I'm not sure what you expect the `set.url` to be. Again, since pelican doesn't do anything special with your custom metadata, it will be basic string and it won't have an `url`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I also understand why set.url will not work.

Comment: This solved my problem too.  Didn't think of using the split function inside the template.  Thanks!